# Dispatching custom event from repeater component and listen event in other repeater components

Tags: apache-flex, events, actionscript, repeater

I have a repeater component with custom event. My repeater components fires custom event holding data. My need is to dispatch event so other repeater components can access data from dispatching component. Any help is needed?

Edit: Added whole stuff here.

```
    <!-- AttributeMapping.mxml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="100%" height="40"
     creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)">

<fx:Metadata>
    [Event(name="mappingChanged", type="MappingChangeEvent")]
</fx:Metadata>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.collections.ArrayList;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import mx.events.ValidationResultEvent;
        import mx.validators.ValidationResult;

        import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

        private var mappedAttribute:String;

        [Bindable]
        private var _sourceAttribute:String;

        [Bindable]
        private var targetAttributeCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        private var _targetAttributes:Array;

        private var _targetAttribute:String;

        public function get targetAttribute():String
        {
            return _targetAttribute;
        }

        public function get targetAttributes():Array
        {
            return _targetAttributes;
        }

        public function set targetAttributes(value:Array):void
        {
            _targetAttributes = value;
            targetAttributeCollection.source = _targetAttributes;
        }

        public function get sourceAttribute():String
        {
            return _sourceAttribute;
        }

        public function set sourceAttribute(value:String):void
        {
            _sourceAttribute = value;
        }

        protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            this.addEventListener(MappingChangeEvent.MAPPING_CHANGED, mappingsChanged);
        }

        protected function mappingsChanged(event:MappingChangeEvent):void
        {
            lblFuck.text = event.MappedAttribute();
        }

        protected function cmbTargetAttribute_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
        {
            this._targetAttribute = cmbTargetAttribute.selectedItem as String;
            dispatchEvent(new MappingChangeEvent(MappingChangeEvent.MAPPING_CHANGED, true, _targetAttribute));  
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:Label text="{_sourceAttribute}" x="10" verticalCenter="0" id="lblSourceAttribute"/>
<!-- <s:DropDownList y="9" right="10" id="ddlTargetAttribute" dataProvider="{targetAttributeCollection}" width="217" prompt="Select target attribute..."/> -->
<s:ComboBox  id="cmbTargetAttribute" change="cmbTargetAttribute_changeHandler(event)" dataProvider="{targetAttributeCollection}" right="10" verticalCenter="0"/>
```

```
<!-- Main.mxml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
           minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns:controls="*">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.events.ValidationResultEvent;
        import mx.validators.ValidationResult;

        [Bindable]
        private var targetAttributes:Array = new Array("Product Name", "Price", "Weight", "Lot Size", "Currency", "VAT", "Maximum Order Quantity");

        [Bindable]
        private var sourceAttributes:Array = new Array("Name", "Price", "Product Weight", "Size", "Currency", "VAT", "Max Order Quantity");

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:VBox width="492" top="10" bottom="10" left="28">
    <mx:Repeater id="attributeMap" dataProvider="{sourceAttributes}">
        <controls:AttributeMapping targetAttributes="{targetAttributes}" sourceAttribute="{attributeMap.currentItem}"/>
    </mx:Repeater>
</mx:VBox>
```

```
<!-- MappingChangeEvent.as -->
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class MappingChangeEvent extends Event
    {
    public static const MAPPING_CHANGED:String = "mappingChanged";

    private var attribute:String;

    public function MappingChangeEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean, attribute:String)
    {
        super(type, bubbles);
        this.attribute = attribute;
    }

    override public function clone():Event
    {
        return new MappingChangeEvent(type, bubbles, attribute);
    }

    public function MappedAttribute():String
    {
        return this.attribute;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code has no repeater; are you sure you posted the right code segment to go with this question?

Comment: Fixed code to include main app also.

Comment: Try again w/ a runnable sample.  Right now you just have a mish-mash of stuff w/ no relation to each other.

Comment: Done. Edited the first post. Thanks Jeffry!

Comment: +1 for the edits to include better code.

Comment: What Im trying to do is mapping component for mapping data from external data file to database.

Answer (score 1):

Oh dear, what a mashup of Flex 3 and Flex 4.  If you're going to use Flex 4, use all Spark components.  VBox, Canvas, Repeater all have Spark equivalent; VGroup, Group and DataGroup respectively.

I would recommend you use DataGroup instead of Repeater since repeater has been known to have problems, plus DataGroup is easier to manage.  Just need to add a custom item renderer to do whatever you want.

The current problem you're experiencing is a problem with the Repeater itself since anything 'child' of repeater is within it's own scope and anything binded to outside of the repeater will fail silently.  This is avoided by using DataGroup and using proper data in, event out concept.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I will try to familiarize myself with  new spark components like DataGroup etc.

Comment: Got this resolved. ItemRenderers cant dispatch events to application, so I had to add eventlistener to renderer parent.